# Why is the letter $\mathcal{E}$ used to denote the dual of the space of smooth functions?

Tags: functional-analysis, soft-question, notation, topological-vector-spaces

In the theory of Topological Vector Spaces, there are several examples of function spaces and their duals. For example, $\mathcal{D}(\Omega)$ (the smooth function with compact support in $\Omega$) and $\mathcal{D}'(\Omega)$ (**D**istributions in $\Omega$), $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ (**S**chwartz space).

> **My question**: I would like to know if there is any reason or what was the reason for denoting by $\mathcal{E}'(\Omega)$ the space of distributions with compact support in $\Omega$. That is, why use the letter **$\mathcal{E}$**?

Generally the notation has some relation with the name of the space or with some property of it. But in this case, I can't see that.

Comment: It comes after $\mathcal D$?

Comment: Sometimes "confusing" letters come from other languages. For example, it is sometimes customary to see $E^n$ for the unit disk, since in German it is *Einheitskreis*. Maybe something like this is going here...

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Yes, I was thinking about that possibility.  As noted above, it may only be an alphabetical issue.

Comment: The "S" for Schwartz space is not because of the name "Schwartz" but it stands for "Spherical". In fact LS first defined $S'$ as the distributions in $D'$ which come from distributions on the sphere via restriction to $S^n\backslash\{\infty\}=\mathbb{R}^n$, then he identified this space as the dual of $S$.